# update data inside app each time i recieved a notification while app is open xamarin forms C# code ui?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, foreground

Hi I'm using the puglin **FirebasePushNotification**.
And i have my view with c# code and working width xamarin forms

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
{
    //EJECUTAR ESTE METODO [OnNotificationReceived] POR DEFECTO Y NO CUANDO HAGA CLICK EN EL EVENTO
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Enter OnNotificationReceived");
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p.Data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        FirebasePushNotificactionData myobject;
        myobject = new FirebasePushNotificactionData();
        myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirebasePushNotificactionData>(json);
        txtUsuario.Text = myobject.nombreUsuario;
        //obtenerDatosDelServicioZonasTrabajoAsync(myobject.codigo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("error: " + ex.Message);
    }
};
```

**and the error *ex.Message* is**

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views

the label **(txtUsuario.Text)** update with the correct data of the notification for the first time and this error only shows the first time too.

always enter in OnNotificationReceived. That's good but  only the first time update the label.

Comment: Have you tried to Run on UI thread to update the label?

Comment: There is no guarantee what thread the `OnNotificationReceived` method will run on, it may run on the ui thread or it may not. So Bruno Caceiro's suggestion would be the way forward to guarantee that the UI code always runs on the UI thread no matter the thread that method runs on when called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the UI on a different thread. You can call this method, to update in the UI thread.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    txtUsuario.Text = myobject.nombreUsuario;
});
```

Comment: Yes I saw that code in xamarin forum too. It works. :D 
Thanks